# How to automate AWS Elastic Transcoder Jobs for s3 buckets?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-elastic-transcoder

**What I want:** To add watermarks to all video files that are uploaded to the S3 bucket (mov, mp4, etc.).  Then overwrite the file with it's same name with the newly transcoded file that has the watermark on it.

So, I was able to manually do this by creating a pipeline and job with elastic transcoder, but this is manual.  I want this done the moment a file is uploaded to the server, overwrite the file with the new file and boom.

One, this should be a feature already but not sure why it isnt.

And two, How can I have this automatically done?  Any advise? I know its possible just not sure exactly where to start here

Answer (score 2):

You need S3 bucket, a lambda along with your transcoder pipeline.

Elastic transcoder is backbone of your process.
To automate transcoding, create lambda function which gets triggered by an S3 event .

More detailed explanation is [here](https://read.acloud.guru/easy-video-transcoding-in-aws-7a0abaaab7b8) .

Comment: While this may answer the question; posting a link as primary information source is not the best way to answer a question. The link might become invalid after time.

Comment: Edited with explanation

Comment: I got as far as automating the lamdba.  now i can't figure out how to specify to simply trigger on upload.  it requires an input key, but i don't see how i can just do somoething like `#{}` or File.name, idk?

Comment: it wants to me specify the actual name of the file, which i can't do because i wont know the name that is given and active storage randomizes everything